# Webpack : php file not found

Tags: javascript, php, webpack

I'm working on a project using Webpack and everything was fine until I had to write something in a database. I usually go for PHP and MySQL. I added Jquery to the project and made an AJAX call :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "scripts/addSetup.php",
    data: data,
    encode: true,
    success: function(){
        console.log("Ajax working");
    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert("AJAX error in request: " + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    }
});
```

When it's triggered, I get the alert message :
Cannot POST /scripts/addSetup.php\n\n\n",
"status": 404,
"statusText": "Not Found"

Which means he cannot find the addSetup.php. Relatively to the index.js file (which contains the AJAX call), the addSetup.php is in "static/scripts/addSetup.php".

The content of the static file is copied when webpack builds everything; when running, it's in "scripts/addSetup.php".

What can I do to make it work? I guess I have to setup apache (I normally use Wamp) for the php file to work but I don't know how to "combine" it with webpack either.

I tried to add the php-loader module in my webpack.config.js :

```
{
    test: /\.php$/i,
    use: "php-loader"
}
```

It didn't change anything.

Thank you for your help

Edit : I put the script somewhere else on my server and added a rule in the .htaccess and now it works. Doesn't really "fix" the problem but I'm happy with that solution !

Comment: What is the '\n\n\n' in the path? Checkout it in your js script.

Comment: @NikolaiKushpela It's only in the error message, there's nothing more in the actual code, I checked with the "display all characters" option in notepad++ :)

Comment: Ok. Checkout how your server treat this path.

Comment: @NikolaiKushpela Not sure what you mean but it looks for "http://localhost:8080/scripts/addSetup.php", which is the correct path. When I go to that URL, it downloads the php file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the script somewhere else on my server and added a rule in the .htaccess and now it works. Doesn't really "fix" the problem but I'm happy with that solution !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).